# New Sprite Frame remains as same of previous Sprite Frame

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, texture2d

I am beginner in the Cocos2D gaming. When I change the Sprite with

```
[sprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"anotherSprite.png"]];
```

When I am changing this image in the scheduler it takes the previous sprite Frame rather than new one. How can I use the new Sprite image into the Previous Sprite Image Object

Answer (score 0):

Is your the sprite frame you'd like to use already in the cache?

Use

```
    [sprite setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"newSprite.png"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply... but I wanted to know whether it uses the Atlas Sprite or Sprite Sheet? I am unable to get the frame of the image. @James Webster